# Intel Microcode in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: updates, intel, 15.04

I would like to apply the new Intel **microcode**.
How can i apply the microcode updates provided by intel-microcode ?

My microcode is very outdated.

```
dmesg | grep microcode
[    0.000000] CPU0 microcode updated early to revision 0x1b, date = 2014-05-29
[    0.088431] CPU1 microcode updated early to revision 0x1b, date = 2014-05-29
[    0.901761] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x306a9, pf=0x10, revision=0x1b
[    0.901768] microcode: CPU1 sig=0x306a9, pf=0x10, revision=0x1b
[    0.901776] microcode: CPU2 sig=0x306a9, pf=0x10, revision=0x1b
[    0.901785] microcode: CPU3 sig=0x306a9, pf=0x10, revision=0x1b
[    0.901833] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
```

I use Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Do not expect that microcode will be updated for old cpu's. It may be or may not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

After that, reboot your system and check the output with the command below

```
dmesg | grep microcode
```

---

And here is my *outdated* version, my cpu is simply too old

```
% dmesg|grep "updated"                                   
[    0.000000] CPU0 microcode updated early to revision 0x60f, date = 2010-09-29
[    0.008000] CPU1 microcode updated early to revision 0x60f, date = 2010-09-29
[    4.380563] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
```

Comment: I'm going to do that right now!  ;-)